# Numpy complex128 nan in division

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, nan, complex-numbers

I am trying to understand why I get a warning using numpy's (version 1.24.2) `complex128`, which I do not get using the built-in `complex` type:

```py
import math, numpy

(math.nan)/(1j*math.nan)
# (nan+nanj)

(math.nan)/numpy.complex128(1j*math.nan)
# <stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar divide
# (nan+nanj)
```

Note how the second line gives a warning for some reason, while the first does not. As far as I know, nan/nan should just be nan, without any warning?

Note also that the same does not happen with `float64`:

```py
(math.nan)/numpy.float64(math.nan)
# nan
```

Why does numpy treat the `complex128` version as invalid, while the `float64` version is not? (@Homer512 already pointed out how to disable the warnings in the comments, however I'd like to understand why it's happening in the first place)

Comment: Well the first one doesn't generate a warning since the warning comes from numpy and the first line does not involve any numpy types. The last one (`(math.nan)/numpy.complex128(math.nan)`) also generates a warning. You probably don't see it because Numpy does not generate it all the time. If you had a warning before in interactive mode, for example, it will not show

Comment: You can control the behavior as described here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.err.html

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks! What I am still trying to understand though is why the evaluation is considered "invalid" in the first place? Shouldn't nan/nan just be nan? What makes `complex128` so special? After all, `(math.nan)/numpy.float64(math.nan) ` doesn't raise an error, instead giving the expected nan result

Comment: As I've said, if you write `(math.nan)/numpy.float64(math.nan)` **first**, it will also raise a warning. It's just that the interpreter doesn't raise multiple warnings of the same type to avoid spamming. And it's just a warning. You still get the result. If you don't like numpy warning you about NaNs, just follow the link I posted and deactivate that behavior

Comment: @Homer512 That's just it: On my system at least, `(math.nan)/numpy.float64(math.nan)` does not emit any warning, even in a fresh session. A subsequent `(math.nan)/numpy.complex128(math.nan)` however does emit a warning, but only the first time as you call out. But the `float64` version never causes a warning, which is what I'd like to understand the reason for

Comment: You're right, float64 doesn't do it. Weird

Comment: The warning seems to be partially version dependent. I get the warning `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in cdouble_scalars` for the same complex division you do. Can you add the version of NumPy you're using?

Comment: It's been noted with respect to divide by zero warning, is that the underlying C code does raise warnings, but python and its packages can "chose' to ignore or pass them on.  `numpy` ignores them for arrays, but not for the scalar types.  Something like that may be happening here.

Comment: @NickODell Interesting... I added the numpy version (1.24.2) to the question